# SQL calculations with different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Please see the updated question below**

In my database I have a table with a column (Col) of type float. The table have these three rows/values:

```
100
97.65625
96.0451301148202
```

Now I need to calculate the sum of the rows divided by number of rows for use in a view `((100 + 97.65625 + 96.045130114820225) / 3)`:

```
Select ...
, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Col) FROM MyTable), 0) / (SELECT COUNT(Col) FROM MyTable) As CalcResult
```

In the database it gives me ~97.16 - but if I do the same calculation on the calculator or in Excel it gives me ~97.90

In my datamodel i have `public double CalcResult { get; set; }`

What is causing the difference? I think it's too big to be just about precision/accuracy?

**Update:**

I found out why I get other calculations than expected - but I don't understand why.

I have a table of Participants:

```
Id    TeamId    Name    W1    W2
```

I've created a view, where I calculate an index for each participant `(W1 / W2) * 100`. Like this:

```
Id    TeamId    Name    W1    W2    Index
1     1         P1      72    77.25 93.2038835
2     1         P2      69.3  73    94.9315068
3     1         P3      0     0     100
4     2         P4      62.5  64    97.65625
5     3         P5      0     0     100
```

Next I have a view based on another table, Teams, where I for each team calculates the sum of Index from the Participant view:

```
SELECT Id, EventId, Name,
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Index) FROM ParticipantView WHERE TeamId = Teams.Id), 100) AS TeamIndex,
(SELECT COUNT(Index) FROM ParticipantView WHERE TeamId = Teams.Id) AS ParticipantCount From Teams
```

TeamIndex for Team with Id = 1 is `288.13539` and divided by ParticipantCount (3) `96.0451301`.

TeamIndex for Team with Id = 2 is `97.65625` and divided by ParticipantCount (1) `97.65625`.

TeamIndex for Team with Id = 3 is `100` and divided by ParticipantCount (1) `100`.

Each team is part of an event. I also need to calculate the sum of Index for the whole event. Here I can get my results from both the TeamView and ParticipantView.

If I calculate from ParticipantView, it is:
    (93.2038835 + 94.9315068 + 100 + 97.65625 + 100) / 5 = 93,15832806

If I calculate from TeamView (which is just sums from ParticipantView), it is:
    (96.0451301 + 97.65625 + 100) / 3 = 97,9004600333

Why do I get different results? I just can't see it. And what is the correct number?

Another funny thing: if I in the TeamView calculates the (Sum(W1) / Sum(W2)) from ParticipantView * 100 instead of summing the Index, I get this for Team with Id = 1:

```
((72 + 69.3 + 0) / (77.25 + 73 + 0)) * 100 = 94,0432612313
```

A third result.....

Comment: There's something missing here.  If I try this in sql server I get 97.90046... .  97.16 is way too big to be rounding error.

Comment: The fact that the OP is losing that much scale heavily implies they have a `decimal` not a `float`. `float` is accurate to 15 digits, not 4.

Comment: In SQL Server the `Select SUM(Col) From MyTable` gives me 485.79164034446069 and divided by three 97.158328068892132. The data type of the Col column is float. Do I need some casting on the subquery to get the right result?

Comment: @Larnu I thought that decimal were more precise than float?

Comment: `float` and `decimal` both have their nuances. However, I agree with the others, i can't replicate this. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=289e1b57547525f36796e3ab6b2749b8). If we can't replicate this, it's going to be hard to tell you the problem.

Comment: 72/77.25*100 is 93.203, NOT 73.203.

Comment: As a side note, try SELECT AVG(Col) rather.

Comment: @SalmanA Typo. Thanks. :)

Comment: @WynDiesel why can't I do that in a subquery - like `(SELECT AVG(Index) From ParticipantsView WHERE (TeamId = Teams.Id)) AS IndexAVG`?

Comment: @mads so, is the problem solved?

Comment: @SalmanA No. The results is as described in the question. Only that single value was a typo.

Comment: @Mads. Unsure, I don't have access to a SQL Server where I am now, but at a glace there is nothing wrong with your query. Are you getting an error, or are you rather asking for a reason why you can't do it?

Comment: @WynDiesel SQLMMS gives me the error "Incorrect syntax near 'Index'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, a WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required". But will AVG give me another result than SUM/COUNT ?

Comment: (93.2038835 + 94.9315068 + 100 + 97.65625 + 100)/5 = 97.15832806. Another typo?

Comment: @mads, "Index" is a reserved keyword, I think. I had the same problem on DB fiddle now. Check this query i tested there -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed5fcbaf5670c12ad9755f142843ac19

Comment: @SalmanA No, that should be correct.

Comment: @wyn Of course! Changing the name was the solution. But the results are exactly the same as SUM/COUNT